# Ejabberd IQ time_out, what would be the downside if i set the time_out to 1second?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

If i set the ejabberd iq time_out threshold to 1 second, what would be the downside be?

The default is set at 60seconds ---- every 60 seconds the ejabberd xmpp server will ping the device to get a respond, if there is no respond, the server will kill the socket.

I want to set the ping interval to 1 second, would there be a downside to it?

I am wanting to set it to this short amount is due to if a device suddenly lost internet connection, the socket would still be listed as connected. So i would want a fast respond time to see if a user is actually connected or not.

Answer (score 1):

The downside is that your server and client will consume a huge amount of resources (to parse all the packets) and bandwidth.

It is a very bad idea to set XMPP ping timeout to 1 second.